# yii2 insert concatenated string into database with activerecord rules

Tags: activerecord, insert, yii2, concatenation, scenarios

I have a form, where users pick some options, and I would like to insert into DB an additional, concatenated field, based on user inputs. I need to do it on SCENARIO_CREATE (and update). E.g.:

```
type: A
size: 100
color: black

concatenated: A100black
```

I've tried it this way:

Model:

```
class Xyz extends BaseXyz {

    const SCENARIO_CREATE = 'create';

    public function rules() {
        ...
        ['concatenated', 'generateConcatenated', 'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE],

    ...

    public function generateConcatenated() {
        return $this->type . $this->size . $this->color;
    }
```

Controller:

```
class XyzController extends base\XyzController {

    public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new Xyz;
        $model->scenario = Xyz::SCENARIO_CREATE;
        ...
```

I've tried with `'filter'` also in rules, but no success. Maybe my approach is totally wrong, and it can't be done in rules? Please point me in the right direction. Many thanks!

Comment: You have two options:

**1st solution**

You can create hidden field for `concatenated` column in form and concatenate data from inputs type, size, color using javascript on change event (and maybe other js events) of those three inputs and set value of `concatenated` hidden field.

**2nd solution**

You can create method in your model which concatenates values of fields and put its result into `concatenated` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rules are for checking attribute validation but you can do it in rule too:

```
public function generateConcatenated($attribute,$param) {
    $this->concatenated = $this->type . $this->size . $this->color;
}
```

I think best logistic way to achieve this is to remove attribute from `rules` and overriding `beforeSave()` in your model:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $this->concatenated = $this->type . $this->size . $this->color;
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

you should consider that yii have default `insert` scenario for new record and `update` for existing record.

Comment: if I leave it so, will it in both cases do it, right?

Comment: If your mean of cases is scenarios then yes,
because basically ActiveRecord has two scenarios `insert` and `update` until you define extra scenario your self

Comment: something is not okay. Is it a problem if I have already overridden beforeSave() in a Base model, and my models extend this one?
`public function beforeSave($insert) {
        if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
            if ($insert == true) {
                ...
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }` actually nothing is saved into DB. I've deleted custom scenarios, I go default now.

Comment: in your controller put:
`if(!$model->save()) var_dump($model->getErrors());`
   
    and investigate the error

Comment: this is strange. I've commented a field out on the form, and Yii2 doesn't give any warnings or error messages, it simply redirects as everything would be alright. Otherwise, your suggestion works (`beforeSave()`), so thank you very much!

Comment: use my suggested `beforeSave` method with out any change and check the result